# is there any way to open .db file which pulled from android /data/data?

Tags: android, database

I found the file with .db extension in /data/data path of an application I loaded on the emulator, but I cannot open it. Is there any method to open this?

Answer (score 0):

Download sqlite browser from below link.

https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/

After installation,open browser.It looks like below.Click on open database and select .db file from files.Click on "browse data".Then from table we can select table to view.

**Note** :
**Sometimes,Room db won't be displayed in files.So,select All files instead of sqlite files in filters while opening db.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I get a error that .db file is not database.

Comment: If it is a room database,you will be seeing 3 files with same name but extensions with -shm & -wal.you need to download those files also and keep in same folder